# Butter Knife @bind in Activity error

Tags: android

App errors after the activity is executed.

> Error:  D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: activity.rama.navigationtaskbartraining, PID: 9385
>                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{activity.rama.navigationtaskbartraining/activity.rama.navigationtaskbartraining.FoldableActivity}:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to bind views for
>   activity.rama.navigationtaskbartraining.FoldableActivity
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
>                      Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to bind views for
>   activity.rama.navigationtaskbartraining.FoldableActivity
>                         at butterknife.ButterKnife.bind(ButterKnife.java:322)
>                         at butterknife.ButterKnife.bind(ButterKnife.java:237)
>                         at activity.rama.navigationtaskbartraining.FoldableActivity.onCreate(FoldableActivity.java:55)
>                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
>                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755) 
>                      Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required view 'recycler_view' with ID 2131624097 for field
>   'mRecyclerView' was not found. If this view is optional add
>   '@Nullable' annotation.
>                         at butterknife.ButterKnife$Finder.findRequiredView(ButterKnife.java:140)
>                         at activity.rama.navigationtaskbartraining.FoldableActivity$$ViewBinder.bind(FoldableActivity$$ViewBinder.java:11)
>                         at activity.rama.navigationtaskbartraining.FoldableActivity$$ViewBinder.bind(FoldableActivity$$ViewBinder.java:8)
>                         at butterknife.ButterKnife.bind(ButterKnife.java:319)
>                         at butterknife.ButterKnife.bind(ButterKnife.java:237) 
>                         at activity.rama.navigationtaskbartraining.FoldableActivity.onCreate(FoldableActivity.java:55) 
>                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662) 
>                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)

```
/*
 * Copyright 2015 Worldline.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package activity.rama.navigationtaskbartraining;

import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;

import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Thing;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

import java.io.IOException;

import butterknife.Bind;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;

public class FoldableActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Bind(R.id.recycler_view)
    protected RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    @Bind(R.id.toolbar)
    protected Toolbar mToolbar;
    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient client;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.foldable_layout);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

        String[] dataSet = null;
        try {
            dataSet = getAssets().list("demo-pictures");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        PhotoAdapter adapter = new PhotoAdapter(dataSet, this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new RecyclerView.ItemDecoration() {
            @Override
            public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
                super.getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state);
                outRect.bottom = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.activity_vertical_margin);
            }
        });
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    }

    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    public Action getIndexApiAction() {
        Thing object = new Thing.Builder()
                .setName("Foldable Page") // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated URL is correct.
                .setUrl(Uri.parse("http://[ENTER-YOUR-URL-HERE]"))
                .build();
        return new Action.Builder(Action.TYPE_VIEW)
                .setObject(object)
                .setActionStatus(Action.STATUS_TYPE_COMPLETED)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client.connect();
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, getIndexApiAction());
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, getIndexApiAction());
        client.disconnect();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `@BindView()`, @Bind is the old annotation. What version of butterknife are you using? Should be something like

```
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'
```

That being said, what ButterKnife is telling you is

> Required view 'recycler_view' with ID 2131624097 for field
>   'mRecyclerView' was not found.

This means your `R.layout.foldable_layout` does not contain a RecyclerView widget with id `R.id.recycler_view`.

Answer (score 0):

I would answer this question because maybe some people see this error because of making simple fault and solve it easily with my answer, although this huge time gap between posted time of question and now.

Probably you forget or make some typo in the view R.id.recycler_view.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required view 'recycler_view' with ID
> 2131624097 for field 'mRecyclerView' was not found.

This error lines show us what component cause this error. Check your XML file and tihs componenet's id and fix it. That's all. Also as Martin said, using `@BindView()` is suggested in the updated versions of butterknife.